# How to set a broken y axis chart using chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart like this img

[image]

Since the scales between each data has gap so I want to draw it like broken y axis chart in excel. Is there any way to do this with chart js? I set these chart like this

```
scales: {
    y: {
      display: true,
      max: 1000,
      min: 0,
      afterBuildTicks: (axis) =>
        (axis.ticks = [0, 50, 700, 800, 900, 1000].map((v) => ({
          value: v,
        }))),
      stepSize: 50,
      type: 'logarithmic',
    },
  },
```